# UIDocumentPickerViewController: how to open a given subdirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud-drive, uidocumentpickervc, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am using UIDocumentPickerViewController with the import mode (UIDocumentPickerModeImport) in order to let the user import documents from cloud storage providers (dropbox, etc).
Each time the user repeat the import process, he must browse through its folder hierarchy starting from the root of its cloud storage.

Is there a way to present a document picker on a given subdirectory ?

I am aware of the method:

```
[NSURL bookmarkDataWithOptions:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeToURL:error:]
```

But I cannot connect the dots with the Document picker presentation options. I would expect a picker option to present a document picker on a given bookmarked directory url.

Comment: This is not possible with the current API. You should file a bug at bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 4):

You need init UIDocumentPickerViewController with url. For this action you can (and must) use [initWithURL:inMode:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/1618684-initwithurl?language=objc) method. That's all :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerdelegate/1618680-documentpicker?language=objc

Answer (score 2):

You need to try with [UIDocumentBrowserViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller)

UIDocumentBroswerViewContoller has method [importDocument(at:nextToDocumentAt:mode:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller/2927800-importdocument) for importing documents from local as well as remote like dropbox, iCloud etc.